# Crystal Report 2008 Add Command Where Clause parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

Crystal Version - Crystal Reports 2008 Business Objects - XI

I have written a query to populate a subreport and want to pull in a parameter to that query based on input from a user. My question is, what is the correct syntax I need to put in the first line of the 'Where' clause to accept the parameter?

I created a parameter in Add Command it is called `PickDate`

Here is the query I am using in Crystal Reports:

```
   select 
            table2.book_no,
            table2.time_stamp,
            table2.restdate, 
            a.timestamp, 
            a.event_type,
            a.status,
            a.people, 
            a.new_date, 
            a.comments,
            a.operator_id 

    from table1 a, table2
    where table1.book_no  = table2.outage_no
```

I have tested the query, it is pulling all the data, now I just need help adding parameter to prompt user to enter datatime.

Comment: Did you try using the Select Expert in the subreport?  You should be able to say field = {?PickDate}

Comment: @Andrew `edit` thanks alot, that worked, I made mistake it should be field > `{?PickDate}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the Select Expert in the subreport? You should be able to say field = {?PickDate}